# React Native - Developing on MacBook Air 2011, Xcode Incompatibility

Tags: android, ios, flutter, xcode, react-native

I have a MacBook Air 2011, which unfortunately cannot run the latest version of Xcode due to its age. I want to develop cross-platform mobile applications using React Native, but I'm facing challenges in setting up my development environment.

Steps I've taken:

1. Installed Node.js and npm.
2. Created a new React Native project using the React Native CLI.
3. Tried to install Xcode, but it's not compatible with my MacBook.

Issue:

Since I can't run Xcode, I'm unable to develop iOS applications. However, I still want to proceed with Android development. I've tried using the React Native CLI and Android Studio, but I'm facing difficulties in setting up the Android emulator.

My Questions:

1. Is there any alternative way to develop and test React Native applications for Android without using the Android emulator on Android Studio?
2. Are there any lightweight alternatives to Xcode that I can use for iOS development on my MacBook Air 2011?
3. Are there any other cross-platform development frameworks that are more suitable for older MacBooks like mine?

Additional Information:

- MacBook Air 2011, macOS [11,6,1
- Node.js version: [v20.5.0

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm eager to start developing cross-platform apps and make the most out of my MacBook Air 2011's capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

As you are venturing into React Native development, starting with React Native CLI and dependencies (Xcode, Android Studio) is not the best strategy.

Build on top of the [expo.dev](https://expo.dev) platforms. You will get the best developer experience and the ability to build on Android and iOS without the latest MacBook hardware.